# How do I tell Jenkins to run a Python Flask application, then Selenium tests, then close the Flask application?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, testing, flask

I have a Flask application that spins up my web application to a specific port (e.g., `8080`). It launches by running `python run.py`. I also have a Python file that runs Selenium end-to-end tests for the web app.

This is part of a GitHub repo, and I have it hooked up so that whenever I push/commit to the GitHub repo, it initiates a Jenkins test. Jenkins is using my machine as the agent to run the commands. I have a series of commands in a Pipeline on Jenkins to execute.

Ideally, the order of commands should be:

1. Spin up the Flask web application
2. Run the Selenium tests
3. Terminate the Flask web application

[image: Running Flask and Selenium in parallel in a Jenkins Pipeline]

Now, my issue is this: I can use Jenkins to clone the repo to the local workspace on my computer (the agent), and then run the Python command to spin up my web app. I can use Jenkins to run a task in parallel to do the Selenium tests on the port used by the web app.

**BUT** I cannot figure out how to end the Flask web app once the Selenium tests are done. If I don't end the run.py execution, it is stuck on an infinite loop, endlessly serving up the application to the port. I can have Jenkins automatically abort after some specified amount of time, but that flags the entire process as a failure.

Does anyone have a good idea of how to end the Flask hosting process once the Selenium tests are done? Or, if I am doing this in a block-headed way (I admit I am speaking out of copious amounts of ignorance and inexperience), is there a better way I should be handling this?

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't need Selenium to do the shutting down; I only mentioned Selenium to illustrate why I am doing things this way. The critical part is the actual act of shutting down the port programatically. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Flask Server in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465899/how-to-run-flask-server-in-the-background)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an official way to cause the development server to exit under Selenium control, but the following route works with Flask 1.1.2

```
from flask import request
...

if settings.DEBUG:
    @app.route('/quit')
    def quit():
        shutdown_hook = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
        if shutdown_hook is not None:
            shutdown_hook()
            return "Bye"
        return "No shutdown hook"
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  Creating a shutdown route would definitely work, but I am hesitant about having a route that just anyone could use to shutdown my server. I wonder if there would be a way to protect just that one route, keep it open only for testing purposes?

Comment: You can selectively enable the route, e.g., only if DEBUG is enabled. I changed the example slightly to demonstrate that.

Comment: use token_required decorator to protect the route.