# How to keep AWS Lightsail virtual server running

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-lightsail

I'm new to AWS Lightsail. I'm experimenting with the Nginx image with a static IP and a simple Python Flask hello world application. From an SSH session, I start my Python app. I can navigate to its home page at `http://ip:port`. I would have thought when I closed the SSH session, the virtual server with my app would continue running. But that appears to not be the case. I think I'm missing something basic.

Comment: This isn't really an AWS or Lightsail issue. It's just a general Linux process issue. You are just starting the app as a process inside your SSH session, while you need to be starting it as a service instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465899/how-to-run-flask-server-in-the-background

Comment: Thanks, yes, that does it.